# finding common elements between two lists?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have two lists that are formatted as so:

```
sortedAlt=[['TIF35', 'TIF35'], ['PTP1', 'SSM4'], ['AMD1', 'PRP40'], ['END3', 'RAD26']]
sortedB=[['SDP1', 'SLT2'], ['ATG34', 'GCD7'], ['END3', 'RAD26'], ['TIF35', 'TIF35']]
```

and I need to find the shared elements between the two lists. I have tried a couple things:

These two return only []:

```
sharedEdges = []
temp = [sharedEdges.add((a, b)) for (a, b) in sortedB  
              if (a, b) in sortedAlt]

for (a,b) in sortedAlt:
    print((a,b))
    if (a,b) in sortedB:
        sharedEdges.add((a,b))
print(sharedEdges)
```

For the above code, I'm pretty sure the issue is within the if statement; if I used the same list input for both, I still get an empty output.

If I try to use the intersection function, I get the error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

```
sharedEdges = set(sortedAlt) & set(sortedB)
sharedEdges = list(set(sortedAlt)-set(sortedAlt))
print(sharedEdges)
```

Comment: `[i for i in sortedB if i in sortedAlt]` or `list(map(list, set(map(tuple, sortedAlt)) & set(map(tuple, sortedB))))`

Comment: Do you want to find individual elements such as `END3`, or inner arrays such as `['END3', 'RAD26']` ?

Comment: I need to find the common inner arrays in this case

Comment: When I tried to perform the `add` function on a list, I got `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'add'`.

Comment: Then @OlvinRoght's answer should do exactly what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering inner array element can be non sorted way, sorting them according to the character order then comparing

```
A=[['TIF35', 'TIF35'], ['PTP1', 'SSM4'], ['AMD1', 'PRP40'], ['END3', 'RAD26']]
B=[['SDP1', 'SLT2'], ['ATG34', 'GCD7'], ['END3', 'RAD26'], ['TIF35', 'TIF35']]

tmp_b = [sorted(inner_list) for inner_list in B]
res = []
for inner_list in A:
    if sorted(inner_list) in tmp_b:
        res.append(inner_list)

print(res)
#OUTPUT  [['TIF35', 'TIF35'], ['END3', 'RAD26']]
```

considering the inner list order of element not matter then using set operation as suggested by @patrickartner , this will make time complexit small

```
res = list(set(tuple(i) for i in A).intersection(set(tuple(i) for i in B)))
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner yes this solution Time complexity is large compare to the set operation, using set operation make more sense here

Comment: Sorting the inner lists seems like a bug. The question only asks about finding the shared elements - it never suggests the contents of the elements are unordered. But even if they were, the first solution is unnecessarily inefficient, since it re-sorts `B` on every iteration of the for-loop.

Comment: yes, you are right the first one is inefficient and can be a little improved by sorted b outside loops and using inside again,

Comment: Just small suggestion, better to use another variable name in list comprehension instead of `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the inner lists to tuples, so they are hashable. Then you can use

```
sortedAlt=[['TIF35', 'TIF35'], ['PTP1', 'SSM4'], ['AMD1', 'PRP40'], ['END3', 'RAD26']]
sortedB=[['SDP1', 'SLT2'], ['ATG34', 'GCD7'], ['END3', 'RAD26'], ['TIF35', 'TIF35']]

sharedEdges = set(tuple(i) for i in sortedAlt).intersection( (tuple(i) for i in sortedB))
print(sharedEdges)
```

Output:

```
{('END3', 'RAD26'), ('TIF35', 'TIF35')}
```

This is faster for bigger lists then using a list comprehension with `in` and probably on par with OlvinRoghts commented map - solution:

> ```
> # slightly modified from OlvinRoght comment on the question:
> s = list(map(list, set(map(tuple, sortedAlt)).intersection(map(tuple, sortedB))))
> # [['TIF35', 'TIF35'], ['END3', 'RAD26']]
> ```

Comment: Why should they lists be converted to tuples?

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen, because list is unhashable type

Comment: Yes, this is definitely faster then ones I've offered in comments, I've generated list of lists, that's why there're few `map()` calls.

Comment: @Olvin if you want to answer youreself I remove the quoted one from this answer - just preserving it in case you don't answer and comment evaporates

Answer (score 0):

below (convert the list to tuple and use set)

```
sortedAlt=[['TIF35', 'TIF35'], ['PTP1', 'SSM4'], ['AMD1', 'PRP40'], ['END3', 'RAD26']]
sortedB=[['SDP1', 'SLT2'], ['ATG34', 'GCD7'], ['END3', 'RAD26'], ['TIF35', 'TIF35']]

sortedAltTuple = set(tuple(x) for x in sortedAlt)
sortedBTuple = set(tuple(x) for x in sortedB)
intersections = sortedAltTuple.intersection(sortedBTuple)
print(intersections)
```

output

```
{('END3', 'RAD26'), ('TIF35', 'TIF35')}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way is with sets indeed but **set accepts hashable objects only**. Lists are not hashable but tuples are. So the simpler is simply to cast lists to tuples before constructing sets.

```py
shared_edges = set(map(tuple, sorted_alt)) & set(map(tuple, sorted_b))
shared_edges = list(map(list, shared_edges))  # then go back to lists if you want
```

By the way, please use the snake case (`shared_edges`) rather than the mixed case (`sharedEdges`). This is Python coding convention, see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).